# How to retrieve complex excel file with merged cells and save as xml file using vb.net?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, excel, console-application

I have this that can retrieve excel file and save as xml file.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim excel As Application = New Application
        Dim filename As String = "person"
        Dim file_extension As String
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\"
        Dim w As Workbook
        Try
            file_extension = "xlsx"
            w = excel.Workbooks.Open(path & filename + "." & file_extension)
        Catch ex As Exception
            file_extension = "xls"
            w = excel.Workbooks.Open(path & filename + "." & file_extension)
        End Try

        For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count
            Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(i)
            Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange
            Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

            If array IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0)
                Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1)

                Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
                settings.Indent = True

                Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename + ".xml", settings)
                    writer.WriteStartDocument()
                    writer.WriteStartElement(filename)
                    For j As Integer = 2 To bound0
                        writer.WriteStartElement(sheet.Name)
                        For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
                            writer.WriteElementString(array(1, x), array(j, x))
                        Next
                        writer.WriteEndElement()
                    Next
                    writer.WriteEndElement()
                    writer.WriteEndDocument()
                End Using
            End If
        Next
        w.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("MS Excel file is invalid.")
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

When I have this, for example, as my excel file:

filename: `person.xlsx`
sheet name: `personfile`

```
Name     Age     Gender
John     5       M
Jane     4       F
```

Then the xml file will return this way.

```
<person>
 <personfile>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>5</Age>
  <Gender>M</Gender>
 </personfile>
 <personfile>
  <Name>Jane</Name>
  <Age>4</Age>
  <Gender>F</Gender>
 </personfile>
</person>
```

which is saved as `person.xml`

Now my question is... what if the excel file has merged cells? How to solve the error? When the excel file has merged cells, it returns

```
ERROR: Index and length must refer to a location within the string
Parameter name: length
```

Here's the sample excel file that I am supposed to retrieve.
[image: excel file]

P.S. There are combo boxes too.

Comment: Can you give an example of why would there be merged cells? I don't think it's unreasonable to have some sort of constraint on the input.

Comment: @JBiserkov i added a photo of the file that i should retrieve. there are merged cells and not to mention the combo boxes/check boxes and the japanese characters

Comment: It has to be XML? Did you know that an xlsx file is simply a zipped bunch of.... XML files? Change the xlsx extension to .zip and double click it and you have a bunch of XML files. Now you have your Excel file saved as XML. I guess this doesn't solve your problem though. Do you have an XSD that it should conform to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on a test sheet I made with a couple of different merged cell situations:

```
Private Sub Main
    Try
        Dim excel As Application = New Application
        Dim filename As String = "person"
        Dim file_extension As String
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\"
        Dim w As Workbook
        Try
            file_extension = "xlsx"
            w = excel.Workbooks.Open(path & filename + "." & file_extension)
        Catch ex As Exception
            file_extension = "xls"
            w = excel.Workbooks.Open(path & filename + "." & file_extension)
        End Try

        For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count
            Dim sheet As Object = w.Sheets(i)
            Dim r As Object = sheet.UsedRange

            'Changes to your original code begin here

            Dim bound0 As Integer = r.Rows.Count
            Dim bound1 As Integer = r.Columns.Count
            Dim array(bound0, bound1) As Object
            For a As Integer = 1 To bound0
                For b As Integer = 1 To bound1
                    Try
                        array(a, b) = r.Cells(a, b).Value
                    Catch
                        array(a, b) = Nothing
                    End Try
                Next
            Next

            If array IsNot Nothing Then 'I left this in, though I can't imagine how it could be needed now

                Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
                settings.Indent = True

                Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filename + ".xml", settings)
                    writer.WriteStartDocument()
                    writer.WriteStartElement(filename)
                    For j As Integer = 2 To bound0
                        writer.WriteStartElement(sheet.Name)
                        For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
                            If array(j, x) IsNot Nothing Then
                                Dim h As Integer = x
                                Do Until array(1, h) IsNot Nothing
                                    h -= 1
                                Loop
                                writer.WriteElementString(array(1, h), array(j, x))

                                'No more changes to your code after this point

                            End If
                        Next
                        writer.WriteEndElement()
                    Next
                    writer.WriteEndElement()
                    writer.WriteEndDocument()
                End Using
            End If
        Next
        w.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("MS Excel file is invalid.")
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code treats the table as a two-dimensional array with no merged cells. The best approach would be to apply it to part(s) of the table that fit those criteria, e.g. don't have merged cells in them.

Depending on how fixed or varied the structure is from document to document, this can be easy or very hard.

Assuming the data you need is always in the same fixed place, you can set the r variable to the relevant range instead of the whole sheet.